# Summation notation for two conditions

Tags: notation

I am writing a summation with two conditions being $s,t\in V$ and that $s,t \neq x$ where $x \in V$.

What would be the most compact way to format this in summation notation?

Comment: You could combine your two conditions as $s,t\in V\setminus\{x\}$, so put that in the index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply
$$
\sum_{s,t \, \in \, V \setminus \{x\}} \ldots
$$

Comment: Beat me to it by 3 seconds! +1

Comment: Why is it necessary to wrap $x$ in $\{...\}$? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @James, simply because the $\setminus$ notation normally means the difference between two *sets*. So you make the one-element set $\{x\}$. It's just syntax.

Comment: You could write $s,t\,\in\,V\setminus x,$ but this may cause some individuals' blood pressure to go up. I'd say $V \setminus \{x\}$ is more common, and more correct. But somehow people are not as upset with $f^{-1}(t_0)$ versus $f^{-1}(\{t_0\})$